# Why is PHP giving an undefined index notice for a POST variable when Ajax returns correct, and the POST variable does indeed exist?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, web-development-server

I understand that similar general questions exist, but none of them follow my specific set of circumstances, and none of them really provide a solution.

Inside the same folder on the server, I have two files: `"quiz_maker.php"`
and `"master_data.php."`

I send a JSON object to `"master_data.php"` from `"quiz_maker.php"` with the following Ajax code:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("JSON Question Data Object") != null){

    //The JSON object was stringified before saving to localStorage.                 
    var dataString = localStorage.getItem("JSON Question Data Object");

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "master_data.php",
        data: { jsonDataObject: dataString },
        success: function(msg){
           console.log(msg + "\n");
        }
    });
}
```

Then, in "master_data.php", I receive it as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['jsonDataObject'])){

    echo "set";
    $masterQuestionData = $_POST['jsonDataObject'];
    $masterQuestionData = json_decode($masterQuestionData, TRUE);

    //Perform MySQL Queries here.
}
else{
    echo "not set";
}
```

When I run the code on "quiz_maker.php", the Ajax success handler fires, and I receive the string "set" in the console as I would expect. However, if I look at the "master_data.php" file, the string "not set" gets echoed out, and the following notice is displayed:

```
Notice: Undefined index: `jsonDataObject` in 
/home/sites/5a/0/03891393e8/public_html/master_data.php on line 35
```

Furthermore, all the MySQL queries execute perfectly using the allegedly `"undefined index" "jsonDataObject".`

What would be the reason why Ajax's success handler fires, gives me the string "set" and all of the queries work, but I get an undefined index notice on `master_data.php`?

Thank you.

As requested, here is the whole `master_data.php` file:

```
<?php


ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();

$booleanSuccessfulOne = false;
$booleanSuccessfulTwo = false;

$servername = "[REDACTED]";
$username = "[REDACTED]";
$password = "[REDACTED]";      

// Create connection
$link = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $username);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    $alert = "Oops! We're having trouble publishing your questions and 
    answers right now. Please try again later.";
    die($alert);
}

if(isset($_POST['jsonDataObject'])){

    echo "set";
    $masterQuestionData = $_POST['jsonDataObject'];

    // Unescape the string values in the JSON array
    $masterQuestionData = $_POST['jsonDataObject'];

    // Decode the JSON array
    $masterQuestionData = json_decode($masterQuestionData, TRUE);

    $maxQuestions = $masterQuestionData["statistics"][0]["totalQuestions"];

    for($i = 1; $i <= $maxQuestions; $i++){

        $question = $masterQuestionData["block"][$i-1]["question"];
        $answer = $masterQuestionData["block"][$i-1]["answer"];

        $query = "INSERT INTO `master` (`id`, `question`, `solution`) 
        VALUES('".$i."', '".$question."', '".$answer."') ON DUPLICATE KEY 
        UPDATE `id` = '".$i."', `question` = '".$question."', `solution` = 
        '".$answer."'";

        mysqli_query($link, $query);
    }

    $query = "DELETE FROM `master` WHERE `id` > '".$maxQuestions."'";

    mysqli_query($link, $query);
}
else{

    echo "not set";
}
```

Comment: will you show your entire file? In your question line 35 is not available in **master_data.php**

Comment: @B.Desai Sure. Should I add it to the question or to the comment? I don't want to violate the minimal, complete, and verifiable guideline.

Comment: Add it in your question

Comment: @B.Desai Thank you. It has been added.

Comment: When I run the code on "quiz_maker.php", the Ajax success handler fires, and I receive the string "set" in the console as I would expect. However, if I look at the "master_data.php" file, the string "not set". this sentence is bit confusing. r u calling master_data.php once or twice. if you are calling it once and gets both set and not set impossible. One important thing for ajax function echo the output/result after all the operation is done. mysqli_query($link, $query); after this line echo 'set'; problem might there i guess

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be spaces in the item key for localstorage. The rest of my suggestions are in the chat comments.

```
localStorage.getItem("JSON Question Data Object");
```

Can you try the following below and let us know what happens? Change all of your getItem() and setItem() to have no spaces.

```
localStorage.getItem("JSON");
```

I believe it should fix up this issue because the rest of your ajax & php looks fine.

That said, you can use bracket notation if you want

```
localStorage['JSON Question Data Object']
```